# How can i reveal an element counterclockwise?

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to reveal an image counterclockwise as an animation? More precise i want to reveal some sort of a stroke from a star so it gives you the impression that it is drawn. And all that only in CSS3. Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds complex.  What have you got so far?

Comment: Not an ideea :P I can't figure out a strictly-CSS way for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is based off of Kyle J Larson's post on [How to Create Pie Charts with CSS3](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2011/how-to-create-pie-charts-with-css3/) + some CSS3 animations

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GRR6B/2/show)** ([code view](http://jsfiddle.net/GRR6B/2/))

```
<img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnxxoXUA200QV3f8ERe_3wM40HdwUUhx-Gyvh6Lurs27DcxksSWoUnsMfP" />
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
<div class="outer2"><div class="inner2"></div></div>​
```

CSS:

```
img {position:absolute;top:33px;left:32px;}
.outer {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    background:transparent;
    clip: rect(0, 150px, 300px, 0);
    /*clip: initial;*/
}

.inner {
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(0, 255, 0, .5);
    background:#fff;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    clip: rect(0, 300px, 300px, 150px);
    /*clip: initial;*/
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    border-radius:150px;
    -webkit-animation:innerAnim 3s 1 linear forwards;
}
.outer2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:rgba(127, 127, 0, .5);
    background:transparent;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    clip: rect(0, 150px, 300px, 0);
    /*clip: initial;*/
}

.inner2 {
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
    background:#fff;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    clip: rect(0, 300px, 300px, 150px);
    /*clip: initial;*/
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    border-radius:150px;
    -webkit-animation:innerAnim2 3s 1 linear forwards 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes innerAnim {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes innerAnim2 {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
}
​
```

*note: there are 2 `background` styles per class, remove 2nd to get a better idea of how the animation works*

you could even make the star from CSS (see: http://3easy.org/buildmobile/jquerymobile/#star)

*edit:* added vendor prefixes to jsfiddle

Comment: Can you help me please make it's rotation begin from bottom? You understand the code more and i don't have the time :(

Comment: swap `inner` with `inner2`'s animation to start it from the bottom

Answer (score 1):

the only thing I can think of is to use the [keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp) and animation properties.

using this you could obscure your image by placing it inside a div with a whole bunch of area or div tags. Then using the animation you could 'fade' the `divs` or `areas` out revealing the image. if you get the placement and density of the elements that are hiding the image right, it could look as though the image is being drawn.

[here is a very rudimentary example that uses 4 divs](http://jsfiddle.net/C6kk3/) to obscure a star image. If you made more divs and placed them more densly over the star, you could easily reveal them.

This could probably be done with less CSS, but this is just a simple example.